# Inserting date (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) in Google Spreadsheet using Javascript adds an apostrophe

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I use the 'googleapis' library with Node.js to append new rows to an Google Spreadsheet. This is an example of data that I wish to append:

```
[ 9999, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, '2019-09-19 14:16:10' ]
```

After appending the data I see Google spreadsheet somehow managed to add an apostrophe in the beginning of the date value. This happens all the time, and is an issue as the cell value is now considered a string and not a date and I need a date for my later query to sort by datetime. This is the cell value result:

'2019-09-19 14:16:10

This is the script I use:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const keys = require('../keys.json');

class GoogleSpreadsheet {

  constructor() {
    this.client = new google.auth.JWT(
      keys.client_email, 
      null, 
      keys.private_key, 
      ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    );
  }

  insertRow(data, sheet, method) {
    try {
      this.client.authorize(async (error) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        const gsapi = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: this.client });

        if (method === 'append') {
          const opts = this.buildAppendOptions(sheet, data);
          await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.append(opts);
        }

        if (method === 'update') {
          const opts = this.buildUpdateOptions(sheet, data);
          await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.update(opts);
        }

      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Could not insert raws into google spreadsheet')
    }
  }

  buildAppendOptions(sheet, data) {
    return {
      spreadsheetId: process.env.GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
      range: sheet,
      valueInputOption: 'RAW',
      insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
      resource: {
        values: data
      }
    }
  }

  buildUpdateOptions(sheet, data) {
    return {
      spreadsheetId: process.env.GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
      range: sheet,
      valueInputOption: 'RAW',
      resource: {
        values: data
      }
    }
  }

}

module.exports = GoogleSpreadsheet;
```

I call the code like this:

```
const date = new Date().toISOString().replace(/([^T]+)T([^\.]+).*/g, '$1 $2') // Gives format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)
const statistics = [[ 9999, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, date ]];
const gs = new GoogleSpreadSheet();
gs.insertRow(statistics, process.env.GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_NAME, 'append');
```

Comment: In order to understand about your issue, can you provide your script for replicating the issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `insertRow` with `appendRow`? Would also help if you could point to the documentation that indicated to use `insertRow`.

I tried using the following code and it worked perfectly -

```
function myFunction() {
  const date = new Date().toISOString().replace(/([^T]+)T([^\.]+).*/g, '$1 $2') // Gives format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)
  const gs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  gs.appendRow([ 9999, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, date ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to change the valueInputOption to 'USER_ENTERED':

```
buildAppendOptions(sheet, data) {
    return {
      spreadsheetId: process.env.GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
      range: sheet,
      valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
      insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
      resource: {
        values: data
      }
    }
  }
```